# Comments not getting saved in layer attribute

Tags: attribute-table, value-list

I have to send the shp files for the filling of the attributes to the field agents. To clarify the type of attribute to be collected I want to provide details in comment column of the **Fields** in **Layer Properties**.
The comment details are not being saved in project or qml.
I want to save comment in file other than project (like qml) so that I can send it along with the shp data and it guides the person filling its attribute. We are using QGIS for our project.

Comment: Could you add a bit more info. What software are you using. Both in the field and to author the shp?

Comment: We are using QGIS for data collection and analysis. With the value map we are able to restrict the domain of the attribute property but are unable to provide details on what and how to add the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

From *"I want to save comment in file other than project (like qml)"*, I think you are using QGIS to create the shapefiles. 
QGIS stores its Metadata in the project file (`.qgs`).

[image]

We can open the `.qgs` file by a text editor and read Metadata information.

[image]

Because you do not want to send the project to the field agents, one possibility is a [Layer Board](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LayerBoard/) plugin, which can read the Metadata:

[image]

... and exports it as a `.csv` file. I would merge several layers into one sheet before submission.

[image]